# Load env from database LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Is possible to load env from database? I have a multi tenant system and for every tenant i have custom variables. I set this in boot() AppServiceProvider, but if i use this conf env in seeder, this not loading.

Comment: env specifies database settings. Maybe look at https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings